# Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode

Tags: errors, titlesec

Using the titlesec package to format my titles in a certain way, I have the code underneath; it gives me the following error: 'Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode.' The error is in the subsection part.

How could I resolve this issue?

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalsize\thesection\color{black}\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\thesubsection}{}{1em}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\thesubsubsection}{}{1em}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0pt}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}`?

Comment: Yep! Did the trick, cheers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is due to a typo in a command